# Using regular expression to return rows where x.column1 is contained in z.column1

Tags: regex, postgresql, join

I'm attempting to find all Bill of Lading's (BOLs) that are in one table but are NOT in another table. Table1 contains the raw BOL number and Table2 has the BOL along with some reference numbers/letters. I would like to use a regular expression to find the BOL from Table 1 in Table2 where the BOL from Table1 does NOT have integers on either side of it in Table2 but can have spaces and/or special characters.

Let's say Table1.bol is `405`. I want to be able to find that string inside of "`ASN SMI0168224 BOL 405`"
and return that row. Sometimes, instead of "BOL", it will have "BL #" and/or the BOL will be in the beginning of the string so a simple split will not work.

This is using postgresql so based on my understand of that, my idea was like something below:

```
select Table1.bol,
       Table2.bol
from Table1
  left join Table2 
         on Table2.bol ~* ('[a-z\s\#]' || Table1.bol || '[a-z\s\#]' )
```

Comment: What is your current attempt doing/not doing that it should not do/should do?

Comment: When I use parenthesis, I get this error "SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: The pattern must be a valid UTF-8 literal character expression". It will work if I use "LIKE '% ' || Table1.bol || '%'" but then I have to use a ton of different cases which is not what I want.